# Divide select into various columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

SQL Version: MariaDB 10.4.12

I need to have everything in a single cell, but later I noticed that MySQL truncates the message due to the limit of the length, since I don't want to change MySQL variables I think the best option is to divide that into columns.

The data I'm retrieving is for a month, and want to divide it into 4 weeks.
This is my code:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT
    (
        '[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(json_content SEPARATOR ','),
        ']'
    ) AS json
FROM
(
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
        "day", DAY(`date`),
        "month", MONTH(`date`),
        "total", IFNULL(`total`, 0)
        "placa", IFNULL(`placa`, 0)
        "drying_machine", IFNULL(`drying_machine`, 0),
        "dishwasher", IFNULL(`dishwasher`, 0)
    ) AS json_content
    FROM `energy_kwh`
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ORDER BY DAY(`date`)
) AS json;
```

I can filter by week with this `` AND WEEK(`date`) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) `` but how can I make that into 4 columns?

Comment: What is a "cell"?  What is being truncated?  What does splitting data into weeks have to do with truncation?  And months don't have exactly 4 weeks, so how do you deal with that?

Comment: By "cell" I mean only one column and one row. Right now, with the code above I'm getting all of the data in a single cell, that's perfect but MySQL doesn't output everything because of `max_allowed_packet` I guess

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len.

Comment: I must not change MySQL variables, I need to find another way

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=123456;
```

Or some other sufficiently large value, but don't blow out RAM.  The default is 1024; that is what burned you.

Are you using MySQL or MariaDB?  What version?  MySQL has a `JSON` datatype; MariaDB doesn't quite, hence the need for string operations.

So, be sure to read MariaDB docs, *not* MySQL's.